# How to include .whl files in zip for lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-wheel

Ok...I have spent a good amount of time trying to figure this out. The easiest way to include dependencies for python in lambda functions seems to be a download of the .whl file from pyPI (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible/), unzipping, and including the contents which are compiled on a version on linux compatible with what AWS is running.

Simple question, answer no where to be found. On a WINDOWS machine, how can we uncompress the contents of the .whl for inclusion in a zip file with our python scripts?? I'm desperately looking for a step-by-step but nothing is out there...very frustrated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lambda functions are run on Linux machines, which is why the guide tells you to download the `manylinux` wheels.

You can do the packaging (following the steps in the article you've linked) just as well on Windows, so long as you make sure to download and extract `manylinux` wheels, not Windows wheels.

EDIT: bringing this up from the comments – .whls are just plain old .zips, so you can rename them to .zip and extract.

Comment: Yes, clear on the fact that a windows version wouldn't work on lambda, which uses the linux AMI...what I cannot figure out is how to extract the manylinux wheels. Do I need something other than PIP? I understand this might seem trivial but I cannot find any documentation around how to extract from a .whl zip

Comment: .whls are just .zips -- rename to .zip and extract away! (Preferably not with Windows Explorer's own ZIP tool though, it isn't very good.)

Comment: I did not realize...I thought they were similar to tar files and needed to be tarred or something. Thank you

Comment: No worries! I do have to agree the Amazon docs aren't very good at explaining that fact either.